# Trackmania workshop problems

Tags: mods, trackmania-2, steam-workshop

I can't get cars and tracks on Workshop. When I subscribe to some car or track it says its on (whatever game) which is total lies, for example when I subscribed to the Mini Clubman WRC car it downloads but I don't see it on the paint car screen.

How come people get some and I don't see them ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you need to watch out for when getting custom models.

After you subscribe to something, go to `Documents\ManiaPlanet\Skins\Models\StadiumCar`. Create the `StadiumCar` folder inside `Models` if you don't see it already. This is where you should be placing downloaded car models' .zip and .loc files. Both of these are needed for it to work correctly. After this, restart the game so it can find the new files.

If your router ports don't forward automatically, you'll need to open `2350 UDP & TCP` and `3450 UDP & TCP`. This is required for the game to use your model's .loc file to get it from the internet for other players to see.